# UIView Overlayed over UIWindow Passes Clicks Through SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I need to overlay an `UIView` on top of `SwiftUI` content. Instead of using `UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)`, I simply add it to `UIWindow` hierarchy and apply constraints (I need it for additional customization, not important here).

But I ran into a problem. Overlayed `UIView` passes tap gestures through itself, and underlying `SwiftUI` `View` gets clicked. You can see, that successive clicks make screen redder and redder—they basically insert more subviews.

Weird thing is, that drag gestures, such as scrolling, don't go through.

[image]

What are the implications here? Why is tap going through, and not drag?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(content: {
            Button("Click", action: overlayView)
        })
    }
    
    private func overlayView() {
        let overlay: UIView = .init()
        overlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        overlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        overlay.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        
        let windowView: UIView = UIApplication.shared.activeWindow!.rootViewController!.view
        
        windowView.addSubview(overlay)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            overlay.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.leadingAnchor),
            overlay.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.trailingAnchor),
            overlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.topAnchor),
            overlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    var activeWindow: UIWindow? {
        connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .first { $0 is UIWindowScene }
            .flatMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    }
}
```

The same problem doesn't occur when launching from pure `UIKit`:

```swift
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let button: UIButton = .init()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(overlayView), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func overlayView() {
        let overlay: UIView = .init()
        overlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        overlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        overlay.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        
        let windowView: UIView = UIApplication.shared.activeWindow!.rootViewController!.view
        
        windowView.addSubview(overlay)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            overlay.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.leadingAnchor),
            overlay.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.trailingAnchor),
            overlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.topAnchor),
            overlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: windowView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if you could help with actually cutting off the tap gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue. What I did is setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the root view of the topmost presenting view controller, instead of on the overlay.